# chrome fails to load with python selenium chromedriver

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have tested the code on my PC with Ubuntu 17.10. Chrome launches with UI so everything is normal.

The Vultr instasnce is with Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3, Selenium, Google-Chrome, Chromedriver and xvfb installed. Default user is root.

chromedriver-2.33.506092 is on /usr/bin/chromedriver, while
Google-Chrome-62.0.3202.75 is on /usr/bin/google-chrome

However, running it on a Vultr instance, it gives this error:
https://pastebin.com/RJX6Ynxe

Below is part of the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

This is the service-log:
https://pastebin.com/s6Nw3Jxc

Would anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please paste the output of executed command from terminal `/usr/bin/google-chrome --disable-background-networking ...and the rest of it`

Comment: /usr/bin/google-chrome --disable-background-networking gives [3513:3513:1102/221503.908274:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(88)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.

Comment: /usr/bin/google-chrome --disable-background-networking --no-sandbox gives [1102/221543.036310:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(310)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly

Comment: I saw the "--no-sandbox" tips when I debug and before posting here. Haven't thought of putting this as chrome_options for chromedriver. It works! May you please post it as an answer? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This issue is related to chrome driver only. The cause of the issue is described [here](https://github.com/Googlechrome/puppeteer/issues/290#issuecomment-322851507).

To be specific when you run chrome in headless mode you need to include flag `--no-sandbox`:

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
```